# RSpec: How to test instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

How Can I test @comments, @seller_items instance variables in my **UsersController:**

```
def show
    @comments = @user.comments.hash_tree
    @comment = @user.comments.build(parent_id: params[:parent_id])
    @seller_items = User.seller_list(current_user)
  end
```

Part of RSpec **test:**

```
    context "User logged in" do 
      let(:user) { create(:user) }
      let(:user2) { create(:user) }
      let(:comment) { create(:comment, user: user) }

      before { sign_in(user) }

      describe "GET #show" do 
        it "assigns @user" do
          get :show, id: user
          expect(assigns(:user)).to eq(user)
        end

        it "assigns new comment" do 
          get :show, id: user
          expect(assigns(:comment)).to be_instance_of(Comment)
        end

        it "redirect_to :show view" do
            get :show, id: user
            expect(response).to render_template :show
        end
      end
     end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can both test for `persistence` and `assignment`.

**Persistence:**

This test will check if the instance variable remains across the route, for usage through the response.

*Example*:

```
it "should persists @user" do
  get :show, id: user
  expect(assigns(:user)).to be_persisted
end
```

**Assignment:**

This test will check to see that the correct/expected value is assigned to each instance variable.

*Example*:

What you have above is an example of a test to check for assignment.

```
it "should persists @user" do
  get :show, id: user
  expect(assigns(:user)).to eq(user)
end
```

Comment: so - `it "assigns @seller_items" do
   get :show, id: user
       expect(assigns(:seller_items)).to eq(User.seller_list(user))
     end` its ok?

Comment: Yeah, more or less. I expect this to pass, but personally, as much as I can avoid it, I don't like to call the same methods in my specs as called in my code ( `User.seller_list(user)` ). On the other hand, there are the `seller_items` built in the test that were attached to this user for the purpose of this test. You can check against those, but what you have here will work as well.

Comment: Yes it works! but How can I test on the other hand? :)

Comment: I'm sure you will figure it out... ;)